# how to make asynchronous request using concurrent queues?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Can someone help me on how to send asynchronous request using concurrent queues. Most of the discussions does not look like it has got an answer.

The following is the code that I've written. When my request is being fetched, my ui displays the activity indicator. Once the response is fetched the next screen is to be displayed

```
    __block NSData *postReply;
 __block NSDictionary *jsonDict;
myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", Nil);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"%@",request);
 jsonDict=(NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
 postReply=data;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if ([[jsonDict objectForKey:@"result"]isEqualToString:@"Success"]) {

                UIStoryboard *strObj=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                ViewController1 *v1=[strObj instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view1"];
                [self presentViewController:v1 animated:YES completion:^{
                    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                }];
            }

        });

    }];
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  What doesn't work? The outer dispatch_async is effectively pointless because you immediately perform another asynchronous request. Stopping and removing the activity indicator after you present a new view controller is also odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 __block NSData *postReply;
    __block NSDictionary *jsonDict;

        [activityIndicator startAnimating];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            NSLog(@"%@",request);
            jsonDict=(NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
            postReply=data;
                if ([[jsonDict objectForKey:@"result"]isEqualToString:@"Success"]) {

                    UIStoryboard *strObj=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                    ViewController1 *v1=[strObj instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view1"];
                    [self presentViewController:v1 animated:YES completion:^{
                        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                        [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                    }];
                }



        }];
```

I think this may help you.

Comment: Hi suyash. I am a toddler in iPhone App development. Thanks a lot. Much appreciate your help

Comment: @MaliniRam you can find solution of your problem or not.

Comment: then Like this answer for others.